# Where is cuda-memcheck?

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I have CUDA installed on my Debian 11 through [the official way](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Debian&target_version=11&target_type=deb_local):

```
$ wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/12.1.0/local_installers/cuda-repo-debian11-12-1-local_12.1.0-530.30.02-1_amd64.deb
$ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-debian11-12-1-local_12.1.0-530.30.02-1_amd64.deb
$ sudo cp /var/cuda-repo-debian11-12-1-local/cuda-*-keyring.gpg /usr/share/keyrings/
$ sudo add-apt-repository contrib
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Tue_Feb__7_19:32:13_PST_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.1, V12.1.66
Build cuda_12.1.r12.1/compiler.32415258_0

$ which nvcc
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc
```

Now I couldn't find `cuda-memcheck` and unfortunetly [CUDA-MEMCHECK User Manual](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-memcheck) is missing:

```
$ cd /usr/local/cuda
$ find . -name cuda-memcheck
# found nothing
```

Can someone tell me where is `cuda-memcheck`?

Comment: `cuda-memcheck` was *deprecated* in favor of `compute-sanitizer` starting with CUDA 11.5. Deprecation means the functionality is scheduled for removal in future versions of CUDA. Since you are using CUDA 12.1, this *may* have happened already (I have *not* checked to confirm, but it seems likely).

Comment: From the [CUDA 12.0 release notes](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/12.0.0/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html): " *CUDA-MEMCHECK is removed from CUDA 12.0, and has been replaced with Compute Sanitizer.* "

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [release notes](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/archive/12.0.0/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html#deprecated-features) for CUDA 12:

> CUDA-MEMCHECK is removed from CUDA 12.0, and has been replaced with
> Compute Sanitizer.

If you want to perform memory correctness analysis, you will need to use the [memcheck tool](https://docs.nvidia.com/compute-sanitizer/ComputeSanitizer/index.html#memcheck-tool) in the compute sanitizer instead.

[answer assembled from comments to get question off unanswer list for the CUDA tag].

Comment: And the line you're probably looking for: `compute-sanitizer --tool memcheck [sanitizer_options] app_name [app_options]`